# Appium Parallel execution (Emulator and real device)

Tags: appium, selenium-grid

Iam automating an android app. I would like to know  is there a way to run the tests parallely between emulator and a real device at the same time? Could you help me with the process? When i do adb devices, i see it recognizes "emulator-5554" and not the name that i gave while setting up the emulator.

Answer (score 1):

First run command to get list of emulators are running

```
adb devices
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WRZpF.jpg)

in above image emulator-5554 and emulator-5556 are udid

Now, if you want to run parallel test in both devices, you need to start 2 appium servers as below with unique port and bootstarp port

first go to the directory where main.js is available using command line, and type below command to run 2 appium servers respectively

```
appium -p 1901 -U emulator-5554 -bp 2345
```

(This will open one appium server and it will return URI:**0.0.0.0:1901**

Now start another appium
    appium -p 1902 -U emulator-5556 -bp 2345 
(This will open another appium server and it will return URI:**0.0.0.0:1902**

Now, you are set and you can use both URL in different test and execute your TestNG